# Error on updating contact after upgrade to CiviCRM 5.10.3

Tags: drupal, core, 5.10.x

After upgrade to CiviCRM 5.10.3 (Drupal 7, php 5.64) I can do AJAX edits like view and edit address, but if I edit a contact and save them normally, I get 
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

Comment: If this is still an issue, turn on backtraces (**Administer >> System Settings >> Debugging and Error Handling**) and repeat the action that causes the error.  You can edit the question to include the backtrace, which assists in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM 5.10.3 is not compatibile with so old PHP 5.64. Maybe here is a problem, look at requirements:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php

Comment: Actually it states it is compatible: compatible but not recommended due to to PHP end-of life in Dec 2018